Angular/Typescript Decorator To Execute A Method on Observable Emit
I have an auth service, looking like this:
export class AuthService {

  private login$$ : BehaviorSubject<void> = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);
  private logout$$ : BehaviorSubject<void> = new BehaviorSubject<void>(null);

  constructor() {
    // constructor stuff
  }

  get login$() : Observable<void> {
    return login$$.asObservable();
  }

  get logout$() : Observable<void> {
    return logout$$.asObservable();
  }

  doLoginStuff() {
    // various logic, API calls, etc

    // this is probably in a tap() inside some observable's pipe()
    this.login$$.next();
  }

  doLogoutStuff() {
    // various logic, API calls, etc
    // this is probably in a tap() inside some observable's pipe()
    this.logout$$.next();
  }
}

Right now, for a component/service to "listen" for login$/logout$, they have to manually subscribe to the observables from AuthService:
export class AnotherService {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

      this.authService.login$
        pipe(
           // various operations
        )
        .subscribe()

      // similar block for logout$
    }
}

I'm looking to eliminate the boilerplate via a decorator. Something like this:
    @DoOnLogin()
    onLogin() : void {
      // various logic
    }

    @DoOnLogout()
    onLogout() : void {
      // various logic
    }

The tricky put seems to be accessing/subscribing to the observable inside the Decorator. Angular and Typescript decorators do not seem to be the best of friends.
Has anyone pulled off anything similar?
The application currently runs on Angular 16, if that makes a difference.

why don't you use canActivate ?

What I need isn't limited to a guard. In many cases, various services need to initialize when a user logs in. A Department Service may need to load the departments the user has access to, a User Service may need to load detailed information about a user, etc.

The thing about decorators is that, you need to call the function on ngOnInit for the functionality to even start working, but this is a good idea since it reduces your code repetitions.
Important:
The solution works, but the method will get called on ngOnInit() so we need to avoid executing during this scenario.
The decorators would look something like below:
import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

export function DoOnLogin() {
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: any) => {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (!this.authService || !this.destroyRef) {
        console.log(
          'authService and destroyRef are mandatory for using this decorator!'
        );
      }
      this.authService.login$
        .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data) {
            original.apply(this, args);
          }
        });
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}

export function DoOnLogout() {
  return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: any) => {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      if (!this.authService || !this.destroyRef) {
        console.log(
          'authService and destroyRef are mandatory for using this decorator!'
        );
      }
      this.authService.logout$
        .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data) {
            original.apply(this, args);
          }
        });
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}

We can access the this variable, then we subscribe to the observable, then I use takeUntilDestroyed to unsubscribe when the component or service gets destroyed.
This decorator has dependencies, so you need to ensure that authService and destroyRef (needed for unsubscribe) are imported wherever you use the decorator, you can simply use console.error() when you do not find the dependencies by doing
if(!this.authService || !this.destroyRef) {
    console.log('authService and destroyRef are mandatory for using this decorator!');
}

FULL CODE:
TS:
import { Component, DestroyRef, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { AuthService } from './app/auth.service';
import { DoOnLogin, DoOnLogout } from './app/decorators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    <button (click)="login()"> Do Login!</button>
    <button (click)="logout()"> Do Logout!</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  authService = inject(AuthService);
  destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  ngOnInit() {
    // required to initiate the subscribe!
    this.actionOnLogin();
    this.actionOnLogout();
  }

  @DoOnLogin()
  actionOnLogin() {
    console.log('performing login actions!');
  }

  @DoOnLogout()
  actionOnLogout() {
    console.log('performing logout actions!');
  }

  login() {
    this.authService.doLoginStuff();
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.doLogoutStuff();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

SERVICE:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private login$$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private logout$$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor() {
    // constructor stuff
  }

  get login$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.login$$.asObservable();
  }

  get logout$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.logout$$.asObservable();
  }

  doLoginStuff() {
    // various logic, API calls, etc

    // this is probably in a tap() inside some observable's pipe()
    this.login$$.next('login');
  }

  doLogoutStuff() {
    // various logic, API calls, etc
    // this is probably in a tap() inside some observable's pipe()
    this.logout$$.next('logout');
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
